# Compare PHP Variable value with MySQL Column value

Tags: php, mysql

I receive a post and want to do some actions only if the value of variable received in post exists in a specific column of the table. So i did this:

```
$pedidoID = $_POST["pedidoID"];
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido = "pedidoID"');
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
//Some actions
}
```

So if the value from pedidoID doesn't exist in the column numeroPedido it will do the actions, because result will be 0 (because no rows are found).

What is happenning is that the $result is returning as bool(false) in both cases (if the value exists or not). I guess that my problem is how I'm using the variable inside the SELECT to compare to the column. I've tried to insert $_POST["pedidoID"] inside the SELECT also but my syntax was also wrong.

Does anyone know the correct syntax to use?

Comment: **REMOVE YOUR ROOT PASSWORD FROM YOUR CODE SAMPLE!**

Comment: Try this, `WHERE numeroPedido = "$pedidoID"`

Comment: Change your db password ASAP.

Comment: thanks, guys! pass already changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$pedidoID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["pedidoID"]);
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('<your_database_name>', $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido = 'pedidoID'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
//Some actions
}
```

Comment: its a string. Ex: string(9) "ef65eL167"

Comment: Then try: $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido='$pedidoID'");

Comment: Try to print the query and dry run it from PhpMyAdmin or command line and trace the error.
You can also check with this: $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido='".mysql_real_escape_string(($pedidoID)."'");

Comment: your last sugestion has an extra left bracket. Will it work? For my case not.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the xtra bracket :P. You can try after removing it. If it fails, try dry running the query (from terminal/PhpMyAdmin) like: SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido='ef65eL167'; and check for whether it works

Comment: The try this to get the error:
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido='".mysql_real_escape_string($pedidoID)."'");
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

Comment: Also setting the error display modes may help in debugging. On the top of the PHP file just write:
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: You also need to select your database. Before the query, add this: $db_selected = mysql_select_db('database_name', $con);

Comment: Thanks, @sariDon. That worked. The debug and your hints solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are comparing the column's value with a fixed string, hence your error. Put the variable in the code instead.

```
$pedidoID = $_POST["pedidoID"];
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "Password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido = "' . $pedidoID . '"');

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    //Some actions
}
```

**HOWEVER** this code is wide open to SQL injection attacks, you should always sanitize any input before using it. Which, as recommended, would look like:

```
$pedidoID = $_POST["pedidoID"];
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "Password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query('SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido = "' . mysqli_real_escape_string($pedidoID) . '"');

if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    //Some actions
}
```

Comment: To sanitize your inputs you could simply wrap $pedidoID with mysqli_real_escape_string()

Comment: Its still showing me bool(false) for $result. By the way the $pedidoID is a string (ex: string(9) "ef65eL167")

Answer (score 0):

When you write code that deal with database, **make always sure** that it's not vulnerable to sql injection. Now for your case, you have to treat the post element before using it:

```
$pedidoID = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["pedidoID"]);
```

Then for your bug, you haven't select the database:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
  die('Connection to Mysql failed : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
   die ('connection to database failed : ' .mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM listapagamento WHERE numeroPedido=$pedidoID");
```